# Which exact version of the Secteur is this bike?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, specialized-bikes

I recently bought a used bike off CL but it is too big for me, so I am trying to identify it to figure out a fair-market value for reselling/trade-in. Alternatively, if I could figure out how to make the bike fit so I didn't have to sell it, I would, but I think all components are as small as they could be already (notice the seatpost is all the way down... it still doesn't fit!).

The only identifying features of the bike are that it's a Specialized Secteur and that it's black with red highlights. Near the back wheel it says "enhanced aluminum alloy" on the frame and the wheels say "classic" on them. The fork has a bit of clear plastic. It has two front gears and (I think) 9 back gears. My best guess for this bike, looking at the Specialized website, is that it's a Secteur Double. I am also aware that the wraps, seat and drivetrain have been updated/replaced. Thanks for any and all help!

[image]

Comment: Does that bike have a bent seat stay? Or are my eyes playing tricks on me? If so, it is not safe to ride.

Comment: @renesis the seat stay does in fact look damaged. Specialized does have wavy seat stays on their aluminum bikes, but this is different, the drive side seat stay looks like it has buckled inwards.

Comment: The frame is just scrap metal, the components sold separately may have some value.

Answer (score 3):

Given that Specialized tends to have distinct color schemes for different models and years, I'd say it's a 2013 Compact, which I think is the base model (higher models get 'sport', 'comp', 'elite' etc. appellations).

[Bicycle Blue Book 2013 Specialized Secteur Compact](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/SearchListingDetail.aspx?id=3044220&make=741&model=65142).

Drive-train looks original except for the large chainring.

Bicycle Blue Book gives you a rough guide to value, but ultimately a bike is worth what someone will pay for it.

---

Update: There appears to be some damage to the drive side seat stay. At first I though the paint was just flaking but on closer inspection it seems the stay may be bent.

If the seat stay is in fact bent, buckled or dented *do not ride the bike!!* You would risk the back end collapsing or the rear wheel becoming misaligned and jamming.

If that seat stay is damaged I'm afraid the frame is trash. If someone one Craigslist sold it to you in that state you would have at least a 'moral' and perhaps legal standing to demand your money back, and may have been illegal depending on location.

Comment: It should be noted the blue book price will be for an undamaged frame. The OP’s bike appears to have some serious damage on the drive-side seat stay.

Comment: @Rider_X I noticed something weird going in there but thought it was just a paint flake. See update.

Comment: Ugh, shoot! I don't have the bike in front of me, but if that is in fact true, I'm pretty pissed. I don't think I'll be getting what I paid back for just the value of the parts. I didn't know what I was looking for so I guess now I do - an expensive mistake. How can I check if selling me that frame is illegal in my area?

Comment: @Aylnine Depends entirely on location, and may have no bearing on whether you could get you money back. If the seller refuses you'd still have to go through a court to recover any money.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Secteur triple 2013 black charcoal and red.  I have the same model

Comment: It looks like they made two near identical versions, one with two chainrings (Compact) and one with three chainrings (Triple). I see two chainrings in the photo so that would mean Compact as per the other, existing answer